Build Error: Namespace Not Specified for Location Package in Flutter Project
After login home_page.dart
I'm experiencing an error every time I run this app. The variable humanReadableAddress (used for the formatted address in the Google Maps API via geocoder) outputs correctly in the log. I tested it using print("humanReadableAddress = " + humanReadableAddress);. However, when I attempt to use humanReadableAddress to auto-fill the pick-up address text field in search_destination_pages.dart, an error screen appears with red and yellow text (as seen in the screenshot). red and yellow text error
If I remove the following lines from search_destination_pages.dart:
String userAddress = Provider.of<AppInfo>(context, listen: false) .pickUpLocation! .humanReadableAddress ?? ""; pickUpTextEditingController.text = userAddress;
then the error message no longer appears. After removeing above lines from search_destination_pages.dart However, the pick-up address field doesn’t auto-fill with the current location (stored in humanReadableAddress). This issue prevents humanReadableAddress from working correctly in my project.
Here is the pages of flutter project
SearchDestinationPage.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:users_app/global/global_var.dart';
import 'package:users_app/methods/common_methods.dart';
import 'package:users_app/models/prediction_model.dart';
import 'package:users_app/widgets/prediction_place_ui.dart';

import '../appInfo/app_info.dart';

class SearchDestinationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchDestinationPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SearchDestinationPage> createState() => _SearchDestinationPageState();
}

class _SearchDestinationPageState extends State<SearchDestinationPage> {
  TextEditingController pickUpTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController destinationTextEditingController =
      TextEditingController();
  List<PredictionModel> dropOffPredictionsPlacesList = [];

  /// Places API - Place AutoComplete
  searchLocation(String locationName) async {
    if (locationName.length > 1) {
      String apiPlacesUrl =
          "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=$locationName&key=$googleMapKey&components=country:in";

      var responseFromPlacesAPI =
          await CommonMethods.sendRequestToAPI(apiPlacesUrl);

      if (responseFromPlacesAPI == "error") {
        return;
      }

      if (responseFromPlacesAPI["status"] == "OK") {
        var predictionResultInJson = responseFromPlacesAPI["predictions"];
        var predictionsList = (predictionResultInJson as List)
            .map((eachPlacePrediction) =>
                PredictionModel.fromJson(eachPlacePrediction))
            .toList();

        setState(() {
          dropOffPredictionsPlacesList = predictionsList;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String userAddress = Provider.of<AppInfo>(context, listen: false)
            .pickUpLocation!
            .humanReadableAddress ??
        "";
    pickUpTextEditingController.text = userAddress;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Card(
              elevation: 10,
              child: Container(
                height: 230,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black12,
                      blurRadius: 5.0,
                      spreadRadius: 0.5,
                      offset: Offset(0.7, 0.7),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 24, top: 48, right: 24, bottom: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 6,
                      ),
                      // Icon button - title
                      Stack(
                        children: [
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.pop(
                                  context); // Navigate back to previous page
                            },
                            child: const Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_back,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "Set Dropoff Location",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 18,
                      ),
                      // Pickup text field
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Image.asset(
                            "assets/images/initial.png",
                            height: 16,
                            width: 16,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 18,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                                child: TextField(
                                  controller: pickUpTextEditingController,
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: "Pickup Address",
                                      fillColor: Colors.white12,
                                      filled: true,
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      isDense: true,
                                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: 11, top: 9, bottom: 9)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 11,
                      ),
                      // Destination text field
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Image.asset(
                            "assets/images/final.png",
                            height: 16,
                            width: 16,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 18,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                                child: TextField(
                                  controller: destinationTextEditingController,
                                  onChanged: (inputText) {
                                    searchLocation(inputText);
                                  },
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: "Destination Address",
                                      fillColor: Colors.white12,
                                      filled: true,
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      isDense: true,
                                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: 11, top: 9, bottom: 9)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // Display prediction results for destination place
            (dropOffPredictionsPlacesList.isNotEmpty)
                ? Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
                    child: ListView.separated(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                          elevation: 3,
                          child: PredictionPlaceUI(
                            predictedPlaceData:
                                dropOffPredictionsPlacesList[index],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                          const SizedBox(
                        height: 2,
                      ),
                      itemCount: dropOffPredictionsPlacesList.length,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    ),
                  )
                : Container(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


main.dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:users_app/appinfo/app_info.dart';
import 'package:users_app/authentication/login_screen.dart';
// import 'package:users_app/authentication/signup_screen.dart';
import 'package:users_app/pages/home_page.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "*************************************",
      appId: "***************************************",
      messagingSenderId: "******************",
      projectId: "bhromor-13f57",
    ),
  );

  // Request location permission
  if (await Permission.locationWhenInUse.isDenied) {
    await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request();
  }

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => AppInfo(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter User App',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        home: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null
            ? const LoginScreen()
            : const HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


app_info.dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:users_app/models/address_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class AppInfo extends ChangeNotifier {
  AddressModel? _pickUpLocation;
  AddressModel? dropOffLocation;

  AddressModel? get pickUpLocation => _pickUpLocation;

  void updatePickUpLocation(AddressModel pickUpModel) {
    _pickUpLocation = pickUpModel;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateDropOffLocation(AddressModel dropOffModel) {
    dropOffLocation = dropOffModel;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}


common_methods.dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:users_app/appInfo/app_info.dart';
import 'package:users_app/global/global_var.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:users_app/models/address_model.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class CommonMethods {
  checkConnectivity(BuildContext context) async {
    var connectionResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();

    if (connectionResult != ConnectivityResult.mobile &&
        connectionResult != ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      if (!context.mounted) return;
      displaySnackBar(
          "your Internet is not Available. Check your connection. Try Again.",
          context);
    }
  }

  displaySnackBar(String messageText, BuildContext context) {
    var snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(messageText));
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  static sendRequestToAPI(String apiUrl) async {
    http.Response responseFromAPI = await http.get(Uri.parse(apiUrl));

    try {
      if (responseFromAPI.statusCode == 200) {
        String dataFromApi = responseFromAPI.body;
        var dataDecoded = jsonDecode(dataFromApi);
        return dataDecoded;
      } else {
        return "error";
      }
    } catch (errorMsg) {
      return "error";
    }
  }

  ///Reverse GeoCoding
  static Future<String> convertGeoGraphicCoOrdinatesIntoHumanReadableAddress(
      Position position, BuildContext context) async {
    String humanReadableAddress = "";
    String apiGeoCodingUrl =
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${position.latitude},${position.longitude}&key=$googleMapKey";

    var responseFromAPI = await sendRequestToAPI(apiGeoCodingUrl);

    if (responseFromAPI != "error") {
      humanReadableAddress = responseFromAPI["results"][0]["formatted_address"];
      //This is use for printing of humanReadableAddress
      print("humanReadableAddress = " + humanReadableAddress);

      AddressModel model = AddressModel();
      model.humanReadableAddress = humanReadableAddress;
      model.longitudePosition = position.longitude;
      model.latitudePosition = position.latitude;

      Provider.of<AppInfo>(context, listen: false).updatePickUpLocation(model);
    }

    return humanReadableAddress;
  }
}

Output:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pW0NkWlzcGV9uzSENCEJdzIVV6S5xCIu/view?usp=sharing
